# Git Clone from Production issue

Tags: git, clone

I have an online project under a domain name such as http://example.com. My git folder is under http://example.com/.git
The issue is that .git folder can be cloned into a remote machine. For example i can do git clone http://example.com/.git within my local machine and it will clone the project.
Does anyone has any idea how i can prevent this? The project shouldn't be able to be cloned from a production server.

Comment: I would go further to suggest that your git repository, which I am assuming has source code in it, shouldn't be on the Production Server in the first place.  Instead, you should only have the deployable artifacts on the Production Server.

Comment: Thanks Gary for commenting. Actually my repository is on BitBucket. I just cloned it on the production server. Settings such as private repository and users access on BB seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read about user group, for example here: https://wincent.com/wiki/Git_repository_access_control